# Attribute routing is ignoring verb?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I think that when you have 2 routes whose URL match a request, attribute routing is not able to distinguish them based on the specified verb.

**Can someone explain me why and how I can avoid that problem ?**

I have created a very simple web api 2 project to reproduce my problem :

First, in webapiconfig, only configure attribute routing to avoid any problem with route matching :

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();            
    }
}
```

Then, creates a first controller

```
[RoutePrefix("travelQueries")]
public class TravelQueriesController : ApiController
{
    [Route("", Name = "test1")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1" };
    }

    [Route("{id}", Name = "test1read")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get2()
    {
        return "value1" ;
    }
}
```

we can call POST /travelQueries and GET /travelQueries/1

Then, create a second controller :

```
[RoutePrefix("travelQueries")]
public class TravelQueriesFullController : ApiController
{
    [Route("full", Name = "test2")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value2" };
    }        
}
```

now, you can **not** call POST /travelQueries/full :

```
"Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.

The request has found the following matching controller types:   

WebApplication1.Controllers.TravelQueriesController

WebApplication1.Controllers.TravelQueriesFullController"
```

Now, if you comment/remove the TravelQueriesController.Get2 method, it works.

It means that Asp.Net WEB API 2 thinks there is a conflict between a HttpGet and a HttpPost when both URLs match.

I think this is a bug, but maybe it is not and someone will tell me why :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [Web API 2 Attribute Routing Controller Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327671/web-api-2-attribute-routing-controller-selection)

I just added the question so that googling may be more correct thanks to the explicit error message in the question